# Active directory - How to know the error produced when changing password?

Tags: c#, active-directory, change-password, activedirectorymembership

When I try to change a password from a web I get the next error:

> The password supplied is invalid. Passwords must conform to the password strength requirements configured for the default provider.

Well, I know it is fired when you try to change the password in Active Directory and it do not conform the password strength configured in AD.

But how can I know which strength is producing the error (time between changes, changing to a recent one, ...)? It is possible to know?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some changes in your Web.Config file as

```
<system.web> 
    <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider"> 
      <providers> 
        <add 
           name="MyADMembershipProvider" 
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
             System.Web, 
             Version=2.0.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
           connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
           connectionUsername="blahblahblah" 
           connectionPassword="blahhahaha" 
           requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
           passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" 
           minRequiredPasswordLength="3" 
           minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/> 
      </providers> 
    </membership> 
  </system.web>
```

as it is given in [Membership.CreateUser - The password supplied is invalid](http://forums.asp.net/p/1112286/1715037.aspx)

Comment: Yes, configuring the web.config allows me to provide some of the passwords strenghts. But some others like "time between changes" or "changing password to a recent one" I think are not possible to set in the web.config. Am I wrong? And also is a ugly think having strenghts repeated in more than one place...